# What is this sans serif monospaced font?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image: Font]

What font is this? It must be very common, it is used in Visual Studio quite often and feels very familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very close to [Consolas](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/consolas/) font :

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Looks like Courier New to me. 
Just type it out on your WP see if you get a match.

Comment: Hi musashi, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. You might have gotten a couple downvotes because we prefer answers with a bit of foundation: a screenshot of Courier New might help a lot, for example. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!